# Show emojis and special characters in JSON file?

Tags: json, special-characters, export-to-excel

First of all, I'm a total noob when it comes to coding, data etc. I'm actually a linguistics student, working on emojis on a Twitter data (also, English is not my first language so sorry in advance).

I've found a data of tweets in a JSON file, which I want to export in Excel. Problem is (besides other problems but well...) that the emojis, and other special characters, don't appear, they are written as "\u0e2d\u0e22", "\u00e1" etc, even though it is supposedly encoded in UTF-8.

I've been looking on the Internet for a solution to convert them somehow, but with my non-existent knowledge of coding and stuff I didn't understand anything.

So I was wondering if there was a simple way for me to do this.

Here is an extract of the code from the JSON file (corresponding to one tweet):

`{"created_at":"Tue Apr 24 23:00:00 +0000 2018","id":988915490096640000,"id_str":"988915490096640000","text":"Melania Be mf dressing let\u2019s be mf clear.","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1197528210,"id_str":"1197528210","name":"Jaz","screen_name":"_jazmynbernard","location":"TX","url":null,"description":null,"translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1020,"friends_count":448,"listed_count":19,"favourites_count":9653,"statuses_count":90870,"created_at":"Tue Feb 19 15:04:42 +0000 2013","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/471470913586614272\/oyXpErVA.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/471470913586614272\/oyXpErVA.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"FF1981","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/985371018150727686\/epRypK_I_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/985371018150727686\/epRypK_I_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1197528210\/1524258835","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1524610800657"}`

I don't know if you can help me on this but if you do, thank you in advance!

Comment: It is legal to use escape sequences for any character, not merely those that the JSON standard requires to be escaped -- moreover, it's mandatory that characters outside the BMP (like emojis), if they are escaped, are escaped as a pair of UTF-16 surrogates, so two escape sequences. Any valid JSON processor should accept such strings and process them properly. Is there an *actual* problem with the JSON shown here, or do you merely *think* there is?

Comment: I didn't say there was a problem with the JSON file itself, the problem is that I don't know how to use it so that I can export it into Excel with "normal" written entries (with special characters and emojis showing normally like in a regular text). Also, as I mentioned, I really don't know anything about coding, so for example I don't know what an "escape" is... I'm sorry for being that clueless haha